# Hang up cadavers

Tags: greek

Some time ago, I read the story about Jason.
During his trip, he and the crew met a people used to hang up dead bodies on trees' branch.

Who are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the Colchians, i.e. the inhabitants of Colchis, a region on the eastern coast of the Black Sea, and the mythical destination of Jason and the Argonauts in their search for the Golden Fleece. Here's the passage in Apollonius Rhodius's "Argonautica" (translation by E. V. Rieu) that details the funerary practice you are referring to:

> Here osiers and willows stand in rows, with corpses dangling on ropes from their highest branches. To this day the Colchians would think it sacrilege to burn the bodies of their men. They never bury them or raise a mound above them, but wrap them in untanned oxhide and hang them up on trees at a distance from the town. Thus, since it is their custom to bury women. earth and air play equal parts in the disposal of their dead.